# Revoke any right for a user to another schema

Tags: oracle, sql-grant, tablespace

I'm trying to forbid a user from one schema A (tablespace A) to alter, delete, drop, insert on any table of schema B (tablespace B) but allowing it to perform those tasks inside "his" tablespace (A).

By revoking those grants, the user is not able to do anything on B, but also on A...  I want it to be granted for objects of A, but not on objects from B, and the GRANT ... ON ANY TABLE doesn't seem to do this...

Thank you very much !

Have a nice day

Comment: Tablespaces just define storage, and aren't involved in grants other than by quota.

Comment: Thanks for your answer you are right, what I am trying to do, is to get a schema (i mean by that is a group of tables, views, triggers...) inaccessible for a certain user. I'd like to have this user only capable of proceeding on the tablespace it has been assigned to... Sorry if the terms are not correct, I hope you understand my idea...

Comment: There is no single command to block access to an object. You could start by querying `user_tab_privs_recd where owner = 'B' and type = 'TABLE'` and using that to drive a script that revoked each grant, but that wouldn't cover roles, which themselves could be granted to other roles, and there is the `SELECT ANY TABLE` system privilege, so it could prove a bit of an exercise.

Comment: Thanks it is not the best idea indeed !

Comment: Regarding tablespaces, I think the word you are looking for is [`schema`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/intro.htm#CNCPT940) ;)